# How to summarise different date ranges using this week, last week, etc?

Tags: views

I would like to display a table or graph showing revenue over the last year with sums divided into weeks or months.

I record every sale/value in an entity, and can show ie "total this week" or "total this year" with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and aggregation, but I would like to show it like "this week", "last week", "last week -1" without having to make a view or attachment for each value.

Is this possible without making a new entity ?

**Notes**:

- I want to use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), but I wonder if there is a way to group/aggregate values without having to make a new view for each aggregation (week or year). Then I will have to make 52 views/attachments for showing weeks and 12 to show the year.
- I can create a date field in my view and format it as year-month eg 2014-12 and then group by that and use aggregation. But then I will have to make one for 2014-11, 2014-10, 2014-09, etc

Comment: why don't you want to use views ? Where do you want the table ? on a page or in a block on a node etc ?

Comment: I want to use views, but I was wondering if there is a way to group/aggregate values without having to make a new view for each aggregation (week or year). Then I will have to make 52 views/attachments for showing weeks and 12 to show the year.

Comment: perhaps you can create a date field in your view and format it as year-month eg 2014-12 then you can group by that and use aggregation.

Comment: Yes, that I can do, but then I will have to make one for 2014-11, 2014-10, 2014-09 etc.

Answer (score 0):

"Date Views" (`date_views`) sub-module of the [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module extends the "Configure filter criterion" used in [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). It allows for using "**Relative dates**" that are computed when the view is displayed.

Some examples are:

- now
- now + 1 days
- -2 months
- Monday next week
- ...